# Luggage storage for a few hours in Las Vegas?

Tags: luggage-storage, las-vegas

I'm traveling to Las Vegas for a conference, and unfortunately my flight arrive several (4-5) hours before check-in, and my flight out is several (4-5) hours after check out.  It'd be nice to be able to wander the Strip since this is my first time here, but I don't want to be hauling my luggage around while I kill time.  I'll be staying at a hotel on the Strip.  Are there luggage lockers or anything similar that would be possible to use?

Comment: In such cases I always use the hotel itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Hotel Luggage Storage

Your hotel will most probably allow you to store luggage before check-in and after check-out. [This tripadvisor thread](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g45963-i10-k5053164-Storage_Lockers-Las_Vegas_Nevada.html) indeed seems to agree with this hypothesis. To confirm this you can try contacting your hotel.

### Airport Luggage Storage

There used to be luggage storage facilities in Las Vegas McCarran Airport. As of may 2016 these seem to be discontinued.

### BagsToGo

There is also a private paying service called [BagsToGo](http://bagstogo.net/faq.php) which offers luggage storage facilities. Quoting from their website:

> #### 3. What are the service offerings?
>
> Baggage Storage: Allows passengers to store bags at the Fort Lauderdale-Hollywood International Airport and in Las Vegas at our Off-Airport location for up to 30 days, with valid I.D. and proof of travel within the requested storage time.
>
> [...]
>
> #### 5. How much does it cost?
>
> For Baggage Storage, the cost is $7 per bag, per calendar day.

Comment: I called the hotel and confirmed I can leave my bags at the bellhop area prior to and after checkin / checkout.  (Airport wouldn't really work for me since I'd have to go back and forth to do that).

Comment: I recently tried to use the airport luggage storage, and it appears to be discontinued.

Comment: @DJClayworth temporarily or  permanently?

Comment: Permanently as far as I can tell