# How early can you check your bags with Frontier for US-Domestic flights?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, frontier-airlines

We are going to Las Vegas and have a 6:30PM return flight on Frontier (returning to US city).  We would like to rent a car at noonish and explore the desert for a while.  So can we check in our bags that early and what time do we need to be back at the airport?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Frontier Baggage Requirements](https://content.flyfrontier.com/travel-information/baggage):

> WHAT TIME CAN BAGS BE CHECKED?
>
> You can check your bags up to two hours prior to your departure, so you have plenty of time to relax at the airport. Just be sure to check the Airport & Terminal info at the airport you’re flying out of, as airports in smaller cities can have different policies.
>
> *Remember: For domestic flights you must be checked in with your baggage checked no later than 45 minutes before you departure and 60 minutes before departure for international flights.

For six hours before your flight, you will have to either take your bags with you, or store them in a [bag locker at the airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44525/luggage-storage-for-a-few-hours-in-las-vegas).

Comment: That SUCKS.  So we would have to be there one a little earlier but guess we could just keep them in the rental car.  Is the 2 hour thing normal in the US across all airlines?

Comment: @blankip: Yes, 2 hours is probably typical. The airport doesn't want to become a free baggage storage service.

Comment: You could probably update your answer to reflect more airlines or most (with a disclaimer to check) to have a more encompassing answer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @blankip The rules vary a lot between airlines, and even between travel class / frequent flier status.

Comment: @Gagravarr - So you are suggesting a multi-column chart!

Comment: @blankip Nope, one question per airline of interest

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was 3 hours last time I asked Southwest in Chicago.